# linux shell title case

Tags: linux, shell, variables

I am wrinting a shell script and have a variable like this: `something-that-is-hyphenated`.

I need to use it in various points in the script as:

`something-that-is-hyphenated`, `somethingthatishyphenated`, `SomethingThatIsHyphenated`

I have managed to change it to `somethingthatishyphenated` by stripping out `-` using `sed "s/-//g"`.

I am sure there is a simpler way, and also, need to know how to get the camel cased version.

Edit: Working function derived from @Michał's answer

```
function hyphenToCamel {
    tr '-' '\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", toupper(substr($0,1,1)), substr($0,2)}'
}

CAMEL=$(echo something-that-is-hyphenated | hyphenToCamel)
echo $CAMEL
```

Edit: Finally, a sed one liner thanks to @glenn

```
echo a-hyphenated-string | sed -E "s/(^|-)([a-z])/\u\2/g"
```

Comment: Have a look at this - http://www.linuxpronews.com/linuxpronews-55-20110315ShellScriptToConvertLowercaseToTitleCase.html

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use the same variable name? You're adding a lot of unnecessary complexity to your script.

Comment: I am building titanium project files, and need to use my-project-name as app name, and project directory, but com.domain.myprojectname as app id, and later com.domain.myprojectname/.MyProjectNameActivity to start it up in adb shell on android device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a GNU sed one-liner

```
echo something-that-is-hyphenated | 
sed -e 's/-\([a-z]\)/\u\1/g' -e 's/^[a-z]/\u&/'
```

`\u` in the replacement string is documented in [the sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Comment: Or simply `echo a-hyphenated-string |  sed -E "s/(^|-)([a-z])/\u\2/g"`. Great stuff. I could not find that feature documented in `man sed`. Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Pure bashism:

```
var0=something-that-is-hyphenated
var1=(${var0//-/ })
var2=${var1[*]^}
var3=${var2// /}
echo $var3
SomethingThatIsHyphenated
```

Line 1 is trivial.
Line 2 is the bashism for replaceAll or `'s/-/ /g'`, wrapped in parens, to build an array.
Line 3 uses `${foo^}`, which means uppercase (while `${foo,}` would mean 'lowercase' [note, how `^` points up while `,` points down]) but to operate on every first letter of a word, we address the whole array with `${foo[*]}` (or `${foo[@]}`, if you would prefer that).
Line 4 is again a replace-all: blank with nothing.
Line 5 is trivial again.

Comment: Neat! Borrowed (with adapations) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28344598/874188)

Comment: Nice but this lacks some healthy quotes (and is hence subject to pathname expansion). I would instead suggest: `var0=something-that-is-hyphenated; IFS=- read -r -d '' -a var1 < <(printf '%s\0' "${var0,,}"); printf '%s\n' "${var1[@]^}"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Can you be more specific where it needs quotes and how it could be subject to pathname expansion, probably with an example? And don't you need to reset IFS afterwards?

Comment: @userunknown: here's how it breaks: `var0=hello-*-user-unknown`. (Do it from within a directory that contains some files). And there's no way you can fix this behavior (apart from using `set -f`—which is discouraged). Regarding my solution: no I don't need to reset `IFS`. It's only set for the command `read` (it's like an environment variable).

Comment: Well, yes, if there is an asterix in the variablename, but the example only contained letters and hyphens, so this is a very wide assumption.

Comment: The thing is that (as you can see) your answer is taken to be used in a slightly different context, where pathname expansion could really be a problem…

Comment: Yet, here's a sensible case where it fails: if you're in a directory containing the files `array2` and `array4`, then your method breaks with `var0=my-pretty-array[42]`. In general it is very bad to have to be in a situation where there's a potential pathname expansion possible. Avoid it at all costs (even if you think you truly control all the parameters, you might someday copy that snippet and use it in a context where it will have terrible consequences). When you need string splitting, don't use the shell's word breaking (dangerous) facility, use `read`. You'll be pathname-expansion safe.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I disagree about the recommendation to don't do  something at all costs. Simple solutions for simple problems are all right. If I know about the danger of pathname expansion and that a solution is simple and only works with simple letters, I will know it tomorrow too. Maybe I like to pay the costs tomorrow but not today.

Comment: That's your point of view. Mine is different: if you have the choice between a broken method and a robust one, use the robust one. That will pay in the long run. Now, if you want to stick with broken code, that's fine, but at least warn the other readers that it's broken code.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: It's not broken. Every code has a context where it is used for and where it will work in. If it doesn't work for the specified task, then it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function:

```
hypenToCamel() { 
    tr '-' '\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", toupper(substr($0,0,1)), substr($0,2)}'
}

CAMEL=$(echo something-that-is-hyphenated | hypenToCamel)
echo $CAMEL
```

Comment: does not quite work - but got it to work with some edits (adding to my question now)

Comment: was just the `substr` in `toupper` that needed to be `substr($0,1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

In the shell you are stuck with being messy:

```
   aa="aaa-aaa-bbb-bbb"
   echo " $aa" | sed -e 's/--*/ /g' -e 's/ a/A/g' -e 's/ b/B/g' ... -e 's/  *//g'
```

Note the carefully placed space in the echo and the double space in the last -e.

I leave it as an exercise to complete the code.

In perl it is a bit easier as a one-line shell command:

```
perl -e 'print map{ $a = ucfirst; $a =~ s/ +//g; $a} split( /-+/, $ARGV[0] ), "\n"' $aa
```

Comment: If you are in bash, note also `${var//string/replacement}`.  You could even code the CamelCase conversion in pure Bash, although it would be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, here's a pure Bash *safe* method (that is not subject to pathname expansion)—using Bash≥4:

```
var0=something-that-is-hyphenated
IFS=- read -r -d '' -a var1 < <(printf '%s\0' "${var0,,}")
printf '%s' "${var1[@]^}"
```

This (safely) splits the lowercase expansion of `var0` at the hyphens, with each split part in array `var1`. Then we use the `^` parameter expansion to uppercase the first character of the fields of this array, and concatenate them.

If your variable may also contain spaces and you want to act on them too, change `IFS=-` into `IFS='- '`.