# Recursively concatenating (joining) and renaming text files in a directory tree

Tags: macos, bash

I am using a Mac OS X Lion.

I have a folder: `LITERATURE` with the following structure:

```
LITERATURE > Y > YATES, DORNFORD > THE BROTHER OF DAPHNE:
  Chapters 01-05.txt
  Chapters 06-10.txt
  Chapters 11-end.txt
```

I want to recursively concatenate the chapters that are split into multiple files (not all are). Then, I want to write the concatenated file to its parent's parent directory. The name of the concatenated file should be the same as the name of its parent directory.

For example, after running the script (in the folder structure shown above) I should get the following.

```
LITERATURE > Y > YATES, DORNFORD:
  THE BROTHER OF DAPHNE.txt
  THE BROTHER OF DAPHNE:
    Chapters 01-05.txt
    Chapters 06-10.txt
    Chapters 11-end.txt
```

In this example, the parent directory is `THE BROTHER OF DAPHNE` and the parent's parent directory is `YATES, DORNFORD`.

---

[Updated March 6th—Rephrased the question/answer so that the question/answer is easy to find and understand.]

Comment: I see files containing multiple chapters, but no chapters spanning multiple files. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The book is split into three files: 
Chapters 01-05.txt (this file has chapters 1 to 5)
Chapters 06-10.txt (this file has chapters 6 to 10)
Chapters 11-end.txt (this file only has chapter 11)

Comment: Your edit removed the sample code, so I rolled it back. It's always good to have a baseline to see what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "recursively" but this should be enough to get you started.

```
#!/bin/bash

titlecase () {  # adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969886/874188
    local arr
    arr=("${@,,}")
    echo "${arr[@]^}"
}

for book in LITERATURE/?/*/*; do
    title=$(titlecase ${book##*/})
    for file in "$book"/*; do
        cat "$file"
        echo
    done >"$book/$title"
    echo '# not doing this:' rm "$book"/*.txt
done
```

This loops over `LITERATURE`/*initial*/*author*/*BOOK TITLE* and creates a file `Book Title` (where should a space be added?) from the catenated files in each book directory.  (I would generate it in the parent directory and then remove the book directory completely, assuming it contains nothing of value any longer.) There is no recursion, just a loop over this directory structure.

Removing the chapter files is a bit risky so I'm not doing it here.  You could remove the `echo` prefix from the line after the first `done` to enable it.

If you have book names which contain an asterisk or some other shell metacharacter this will be rather more complex -- the `title` assignment assumes you can use the book title unquoted.

Only the [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with case conversion is beyond the very basics of Bash.  The [array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) operations could perhaps also be a bit scary if you are a complete beginner.  Proper understanding of quoting is also often a challenge for newcomers.

Comment: If you value your sanity, you could do away with the abominable uppercase altogether as part of this processing.

Comment: Your use of `titlecase` function is subject to pathname expansion. You might instead want: `titlecase() { local arr; read -r -d '' -a arr < <(printf '%s\0' "${1,,}"); printf '%s\n' "${arr[*]^}"; }` and use it as `title=$(titlecase "$book##*/")`, (you could even make it better so as to avoid a subshell with the `-v` switch of `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat Chapters*.txt > FinaleFile.txt.raw
Chapters="$( ls -1 Chapters*.txt | sed -n 'H;${x;s/\
//g;s/ *Chapters //g;s/\.txt/ /g;s/ *$//p;}' )"
mv FinaleFile.txt.raw "FinaleFile ${Chapters}.txt"
```

- cat all txt at once (assuming name sorted list)
- take chapter number/ref from the ls of the folder and with a sed to adapt the format
- rename the concatenate file including chapters

Comment: This loses the empty line between files.  Worse, you are [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) which is always perilous.

Comment: Agree partially on ParsingLs (good reference by the way) in this case where we can assume that file are not with special names (need to adapt for ls output). What do you mean by loosing empty line ? is is line  with just a \n in chapters content (work on my AIX KSH) ?

Comment: Because there is an `echo` after each file in the OP's partial implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input. They got me thinking, and I managed to concatenate the files using the following steps:

---

1. This script replaces spaces in filenames with underscores.

```
#!/bin/bash

# We are going to iterate through the directory tree, up to a maximum depth of 20.
for i in `seq 1 20`
  do

# In UNIX based systems, files and directories are the same (Everything is a File!).
# The 'find' command lists all files which contain spaces in its name. The | (pipe) …
# … forwards the list to a 'while' loop that iterates through each file in the list.
    find . -name '* *' -maxdepth $i | while read file
    do

# Here, we use 'sed' to replace spaces in the filename with underscores.
# The 'echo' prints a message to the console before renaming the file using 'mv'.
      item=`echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`
      echo "Renaming '$file' to '$item'"
      mv "$file" "$item"
    done
done
```

---

2. This script concatenates text files that start with Part, Chapter, Section, or Book.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here, we go through all the directories (up to a depth of 20).
for D in `find . -maxdepth 20 -type d`
do

# Check if the parent directory contains any files of interest.
    if ls $D/Part*.txt &>/dev/null ||
       ls $D/Chapter*.txt &>/dev/null ||
       ls $D/Section*.txt &>/dev/null ||
       ls $D/Book*.txt &>/dev/null
      then

# If we get here, then there are split files in the directory; we will concatenate them.
# First, we trim the full directory path ($D) so that we are left with the path to the …
# … files' parent's parent directory—We will write the concatenated file here. (✝)
        ppdir="$(dirname "$D")"

# Here, we concatenate the files using 'cat'. The 'awk' command extracts the name of …
# … the parent directory from the full directory path ($D) and gives us the filename.
# Finally, we write the concatenated file to its parent's parent directory. (✝)
        cat $D/*.txt > $ppdir/`echo $D|awk -F'/' '$0=$(NF-0)'`.txt
    fi
done
```

---

3. Now, we delete all the files that we concatenated so that its parent directory is left empty.

   - `find . -name 'Part*' -delete`
   - `find . -name 'Chapter*' -delete`
   - `find . -name 'Section*' -delete`
   - `find . -name 'Book*' -delete`

---

4. The following command will delete empty directories. (✝) We wrote the concatenated file to its parent's parent directory so that its parent directory is left empty after deleting all the split files.

   - `find . -type d -empty -delete`

---

[Updated March 6th—Rephrased the question/answer so that the question/answer is easy to find and understand.]

Comment: Just to let you know for the future. When you have a _list_ in Markdown, you probably noticed that indenting four spaces doesn't allow your program to be formatted like a program. This is a feature in _Markdown because it lets you indent a paragraph and make it part of the list. To get around this, either don't do a list, or put a paragraph saying something `like this`. In this case, I put `&nbsp;` which makes a paragraph of a non-breaking space, and allows your program to format. It's much easier than adding a bunch of HTML stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Shell doesn't like white space in names. However, over the years, Unix has come up with some tricks that'll help:

```
$ find . -name "Chapters*.txt" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> final_file.txt
```

Might do what you want.

The `find` recursively finds all of the directory entries in a file tree that matches the query (In this case, the type must be a file, and the name matches the pattern `Chapter*.txt`).

Normally, `find` separates out the directory entry names with NL, but the `-print0` says to separate out the entries names with the `NUL` character. The `NL` is a valid character in a file name, but `NUL` isn't.

The `xargs` command takes the output of the `find` and processes it. `xargs` gathers all the names and passes them in bulk to the command you give it -- in this case the `cat` command.

Normally, `xargs` separates out files by white space which means `Chapters` would be one file and `01-05.txt` would be another. However, the `-0` tells `xargs`, to use `NUL` as a file separator -- which is what `-print0` does.